# workbooks.open pulling wrong file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing some code that will run when a button is pushed, opening a .csv file (exported from another program), copy some info, and paste it onto the first file.  Some of the time (and only some) it will actually paste the information from a different file.  It seems to happen when another file is open, but not consistently.  I tried seeing if it was related to which window is on top, or the last one I used, but it's still inconsistent.  It is very likely users will have multiple files open while using this sheet.

```
Public Sub getData()

Dim vFile As Variant
Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook
Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet

Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCopyTo = ActiveSheet

Dim SCOBlankLine As Integer
Dim importBlankLine As Integer
Dim importLastLine As Integer 


'-------------------------------------------------------------
'Open file with data to be copied

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.csv*)," & _
"*.xl*", 1, "Select Excel File", "Open", False)

'If Cancel then Exit
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets(1)
End If

Debug.Print vFile
Debug.Print wbCopyFrom.FullName
Debug.Print wsCopyFrom.Name
```

The last debug values when it pulled the wrong info:
filepath\lc_equip_20180816103532.csv
filepath\lc_equip_20180727090447.csv
lc_equip_20180727090447

Ideas?

Comment: Not related, but for a more robust type check than using a stringly-typed `"Boolean"`, you could do `If VarType(vFile) = vbBoolean Then` instead.

Comment: Have you ruled out user error?

Comment: FWIW I need to squint to distinguish `wbCopyTo` from `wsCopyTo`, and `wbCopyFrom` from `wsCopyFrom`; the pairs only differ by a single character - compare to `sourceBook` vs `sourceSheet`, and `targetBook` vs `targetSheet`.

Comment: Are you showing us your actual code, or parts of it were removed? Because as it stands, I can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Yes I did :)

I added the Debug.Print vFile line most recently- it's interesting that it has the right file but, somehow when the Workbooks.Open(vFile) line comes, it's somehow changing it up...

Comment: Part was removed.  There was one bit above the dashed line getting the last line of data so it knows where to paste: 

    'Get First blank line SCO spreadsheet
    SCOBlankLine = 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(SCOBlankLine, 1).Value)
        SCOBlankLine = SCOBlankLine + 1
    Loop

but that seems irrelevant, as does the parts below that modify the pasted data.

Comment: I have run across some anecdotal reports of `Application.GetOpenFilename` crashing Excel, but nothing with cache clearing.  Have you checked to see if `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)` exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint (F9) on the `vFile =` assignment, run the code, and then step-through (F8) until the `Set wbCopyFrom =` assignment (without executing it), while viewing the *locals* toolwindow, and re-confirm the erratic behavior? (i.e. `vFile` says "A" just before opening the file, and then hit F8 and the opened file is "B") Sorry if that seems distrusting of the problem you're claiming - I'm just as confused as you are at the moment ;-)

Comment: In the middle of trying some of these suggestions, but I think I found the pattern: It seems to be saving the last-opened file as wbCopyFrom.  If the file is open already but something else was opened since, it is using the more recent file.  Still can't figure out why it's ignoring the path provided by the vFile variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the discovery that it was using the last-newly-opened file, I chose to use a different method to open the file and activate the workbook.  Tried lots of file-opening combos since, and it hasn't failed yet.

For anyone who's interested:

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------
'Open file with data to be copied

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.csv*)," & _
"*.xl*", 1, "Select Excel File", "Open", False)

'If Cancel then Exit
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
    Exit Sub
Else

Workbooks.Open Filename:=vFile
Set wbCopyFrom = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets(1)
End If

Debug.Print vFile
Debug.Print wbCopyFrom.FullName
Debug.Print wsCopyFrom.Name
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out why the original code didn't work? I'm having similar issues (also when opening a csv file). It seems that Workbook.Open doesn't always return the right workbook object when multiple files are open.

Comment: Sorry, never did figure out why that method didn't work. The new one never failed since, so I never really looked into it.